# Execution failed for task ':react-native-agora:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: react-native, apk, bundle

i have tried `npx react-native start run android`
i got this Execution failed for task.and i remove node module and lock file than  reinstall(npm) same error.and also i removed agora file after i add `npm i react-native-agora`. that time same compileDebugJavaWithJavac with different dependencies(example react-native-image-crop-picker:compileDebugJavaWithJavac ) than i try same way to remove and add npm i got another error(react-native-agora:compileDebugJavaWithJavac)

```
error:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-agora:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Failed to query the value of task ':react-native-agora:compileDebugJavaWithJavac' property 'options.generatedSourceOutputDirectory'.
   > Querying the mapped value of map(java.io.File property(org.gradle.api.file.Directory, property(org.gradle.api.file.Directory, fixed(class org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFilePropertyFactory$FixedDirectory, /home/ubuntu/Desktop/quaquiz/node_modules/react-native-agora/android/build/generated/ap_generated_sources/debug/out))) org.gradle.api.internal.file.DefaultFilePropertyFactory$ToFileTransformer@49f0db11) before task ':react-native-agora:compileDebugJavaWithJavac' has completed is not supported

build gradle:
uildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "30.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 30
        targetSdkVersion = 30
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
        googlePlayServicesAuthVersion = "17.0.0"

    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.1')
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
```

here i increased sdk version 30 after i got all this error.

before i using build gradle

```
buildToolsVersion = "29.0.2"
            minSdkVersion = 21
            compileSdkVersion = 29
            targetSdkVersion = 29
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this help

```
cd android && ./gradlew clean && cd ..
```

Comment: i used this comment (result: Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/7.0/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 5s
but same error

Answer (score 0):

Probability, it's gradle incompatible. set gradle in dependencies to

```
 dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2')
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
```